# eventListener gets assigned correctly but does not trigger the function

Tags: javascript, frontend, event-listener

I have a class called ContextMenu and it is made to replace the default contextmenu that the browser shows whenever you right click on the page.

This menu needs some eventListeners applied to it's children.

```
        <div id="contextmenu" class="hidden">
            <ul>
                <li id="download-file" class="action">Download</li>
                <li id="rename-file" class="action">Rename</li>
                <li id="delete-file" class="action">Delete</li>
                <li id="details-file" class="action">Details</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

this is the html for the contextmenu

```
export default class ContextMenu
{
    contextMenu
    events
    actions
    selectedItem

    constructor(HTMLContextMenu)
    {
        this.contextMenu = HTMLContextMenu

        window.document.onmousedown = (event) => this.show(event)

        this.events = ['click', 'touchstart']
        this.actions = window.document.querySelectorAll('.action') // all elements that have to trigger an eventListener have the class "action"

        for (const event in this.events)
        {
            this.actions[0].addEventListener(event, this.download, false)
            this.actions[1].addEventListener(event, this.rename, false)
            this.actions[2].addEventListener(event, this.delete, false)
            this.actions[3].addEventListener(event, this.details, false)
        }

        this.selectedItem = null
    }
```

this is the javascript, i did not paste the entire class, just what's relevant for the problem. As you can see the for in loop takes care of the eventListeners applying 8 listeners in total. The problem is that whenever i click the element nothing happens

Comment: because the event is not "onclick" it is "click", same with touchstart

Comment: thank you, i noticed the error and fixed it, however there probably is another one since it still does not work

Comment: probably need to see what show does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [iQucik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13183946/iquick) said you are using the wrong keyword in your loop. In case you're using iterable objects you have to use **of** keyword otherwise use **in** keyword for enumerable objects.

Some references:

MDN Docs for-of loop: [MDN Docs for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

MDN Docs for-in loop: [MDN Docs for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```js
export default class ContextMenu
{
    contextMenu
    events
    actions
    selectedItem

    constructor(HTMLContextMenu)
    {
        this.contextMenu = HTMLContextMenu

        window.document.onmousedown = (event) => this.show(event)

        this.events = ['click', 'touchstart']
        this.actions = window.document.querySelectorAll('.action') // all elements that have to trigger an eventListener have the class "action"

        for (const event of this.events)
        {
            this.actions[0].addEventListener(event, this.download, false)
            this.actions[1].addEventListener(event, this.rename, false)
            this.actions[2].addEventListener(event, this.delete, false)
            this.actions[3].addEventListener(event, this.details, false)
        }

        this.selectedItem = null
    }
```

```html
        <div id="contextmenu" class="hidden">
            <ul>
                <li id="download-file" class="action">Download</li>
                <li id="rename-file" class="action">Rename</li>
                <li id="delete-file" class="action">Delete</li>
                <li id="details-file" class="action">Details</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue. The for (const event in this.events) loop is wrong, it has to be for (const event of this.events) in order to make it work.

```
    for (const event of this.events)
    {
        this.actions[0].addEventListener(event, this.download, false)
    }
```